# Determine if the object is a parameter of System.out.print/println methods

Tags: java

in my class `SampleClass`, I want it to perform such operation: when an instance of `SampleClass` is included as a parameter of the `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()` method, the object automatically calls its own `To_String()` method.

```
public class SampleClass{
    private int count;
    public SampleClass(){
         // maybe do something here?
    }
    private String To_String(){
        return Integer.toString(count);
    }
}
```

so that when I do

```
SampleClass s = new SampleClass();
System.out.println(s);
```

Can automatically print out the value of `s.count` field as a string, instead of having to do `System.out.println(s.To_String())`. Thank you.

Comment: Well.. Just override the `toString()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, but if the visibility is `public` you **can** override `Object.toString()` instead like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(count);
}
```

And then `System.out.println(s);` will work as you describe.

Comment: You can also call "return To_string()" from "toString()" method.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `toString()` method which will be automatically called when you do `System.out.println(sampleObject)`.

```
public class SampleClass {
    private int count;
    public SampleClass(){
         // maybe do something here?
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Integer.toString(count);
    }
}
```

then

```
SampleClass s = new SampleClass();
System.out.println(s);
```

will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you **read the documentation** of [`println(Object x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-), it says:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first **`String.valueOf(x)`** to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

If you then read the documentation of [`String.valueOf(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-), it says:

> Returns: if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

This means that `System.out.println(s)`, for a non-null `s` Object, is the same as:

```
System.out.print(s.toString());
System.out.println();
```

All you have to do, is implement the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method inherited from `Object` in your class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(count);
}
```

Or, if you insist on using your own `To_String()` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return To_String();
}
```